# Limit of restriction of a function to an open interval.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

This is exercise 4.1.16 from Introduction to Real Analysis, 4th edition by Bartle and Sherbert.

> Let $f:R \to R$, let $I$ be an open interval in $R$ and let $c \in I$. If $f_1$ is the restriction of $f$ to $I$, show that $f_1$ has a limit at $c$ if and only if $f$ has a limit at c, and that the limits are equal.

I will now attempt to prove that if $\lim_{x \to c} f_1(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$.

**Proof:**

By definition, Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that if $x \in I$, then $|f_1(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x - c| < \delta_1$.

If $x \in I$, $|f(x) - L| = |f_1(x) - L|$. If $x \in R-I$, then in order to make the equality hold, we must choose $\delta$ so that the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ is contained entirely in $I$, so that $x$ is forced to be in $I$.

Let $I = (a,b)$ where $a,b \in R$ with $a < b$. So $\delta$ must satisfy $c-\delta > a$ and $c+\delta < b$. Choose $\delta < \min(\delta_1, c-a, b-c)$. For this choice, the equality above holds and by definition, we get what is desired.

Is this proof correct? Are there any other ways of proving this?
Also, I think, by a similar argument, we can prove the converse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, but unless you have to be super explicit, you can skip a few steps in the first direction. If $\lim_{x\to c}f_1(x)=L$, then for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $x\in I$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$ imply $|f_1(x)-L|<\epsilon$. When $x\in I$, $f_1(x)=f(x)$, so you have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ when $x\in I$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$. These conditions are saying that $x$ simultaneously belongs to two open intervals containing $c$. Their intersection is an open interval containing $c$, so you can find $\delta'>0$ for which $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ is true when $0<|x-c|<\delta'$ .

The other direction, show $\lim_{x\to c}f_1(x)=L$ knowing $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$, is where you have a slight problem because $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and you need to ensure $x\in I$. What you wrote can be applied here, and your idea is good. If $I=(a,b)$, pick $\delta=\min(\delta_1,c-a,b-c)$ where $\delta_1$ comes from $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$. This guarantees $x\in I$, and so $f(x)=f_1(x)$.

Comment: This is what I initially did. My problem is with the first part. Nowhere is the openness of $I$ used. So it means that the result holds for closed intervals too. However this is not true. Consider $J=[1,2]$ and $f(x)=2$ if $x$ is in $J$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise. At $x=1$, the limit does not exist but the restriction $f_1(x)=2$ has a limit there. This led me to think the problem was because $x$ could lie outside $I$. But I think I'm wrong. I have no problems with the second part.

Comment: @DS2830 For the first direction, the openness of $I$ is used when I say "This is true for $x\in I$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$, so it will be also true for $0<|x-c|<\delta'$ for some $\delta'>0$." The two conditions $x\in I$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$ are basically saying $x$ belongs in the intersection of two open intervals. You can always find an open interval around $x$ which is contained in that intersection.

Comment: Sorry, in the last sentence I meant interval around $c$.

Comment: Oh! I see. If the $\delta$ neighbourhood were large enough to contain $I$ and if $I$ were closed then we have $x$ in a closed interval around $c$. But still $x$ is in the open $\delta\$ neighbourhood so it satisfies the definition, doesn't it? Could you explain why the argument you made fails if $I$ were closed?

Comment: @DS2830 The argument works when $c$ is an internal point of a closed non-zero interval. It fails when $c$ is the endpoint of an interval, whether closed or open. In that case, the conditions $x\in I$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$ aren't saying you have an open interval around $c$ (from both sides). You do have a one-sided interval with endpoint $c$ so you can only conclude one of the one-sided limits of $f(x)$ equals L. The problem hinges on the fact that $c$ is the internal point of a non-zero interval.

Comment: I get it now! That is why, in the counter-example I presented, we were looking at the limit at an endpoint. So, the result holds for closed intervals so long as $c$ is not an endpoint, which is no better than saying that $I$ is an open interval. Thanks a lot!